# What happens to messages when RabbitMQ connection is down

Tags: java, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring AMQP to connect and send messages to RabbitMQ. I'm aware that underlying mechanism exists to handle sending retries when connection is down. I was wondering what will happen to messages and whole app when it's stuck for some time, e.g. connection is not reestablished in certain period of time and messages keep piling up inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one way of handling the situation http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#template-retry

Comment: Not sure at this moment how connectionTimout that is set on ConnectionFactory affects work of RetryTemplates...